# Install both gnu-netcat and openbsd-netcat simultaneously on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, netcat, pacman

They are in conflict when I try to install them conveniently. How can I have both of them at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own package which does not conflict.

1. Use e.g. `asp checkout gnu-netcat` to download the build sources.
2. Edit trunk/PKGBUILD to change the name to something that no longer matches the 'conflicts' parameter in openbsd-netcat. For example, `pkgname=gnu-netcat-renamed`.
3. Edit the package() function to **rename the actual files** that will be installed. For example:

   ```
   mv "$pkgdir"/usr/bin/{netcat,gnu-netcat}
   mv "$pkgdir"/usr/share/man/man1/{netcat,gnu-netcat}.1.gz

   # 'nc' is a symlink to 'netcat' so it is not enough to merely rename it
   rm "$pkgdir"/usr/bin/nc
   ln -s gnu-netcat "$pkgdir"/usr/bin/gnu-nc
   ```
4. Use `makepkg -i` to compile and install the new package.

You will only need to do this once, because gnu-netcat has not received any updates in the last 11 years and is unlikely that it ever will.